# Is there a trick to debug shared groovy libraries without pushing?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm adding to, and maintaining, groovy files to build a set of repositories - previously they were built with freestyle Jenkins jobs. I support some code in shared libraries and to be honest (mainly for DRY reasons) I want to do that more.

However, the only way I know how to test and debug those library files is to push the changes on a git branch. I know about the "replay" trick to test the main Jenkins file. Is there some approach I've missed to do something similar for library code?

Answer (score 1):

If you set up a job to load the shared library instead of relying on a globally set up shared library (you can have both going, for this particular job), then it is possible to hit "replay" and have all your shared library steps show up as editable files.

This can be helpful in iterative development without a million commits.

EDIT: Here's how that looks on an Organization job in Jenkins.

[image: Organization Job Config]

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on that, exactly how are you loading the library? I'm normally using the library function. I've also tried @Library. Neither of those work. What are you using?

Comment: Ahhh, I haven't used the step, I use the autoloading from the job or system configurations. Lemme edit the answer.

Comment: I have the same issue here, can t find a way to edit the shared library, the pic attached does not show up for me. Could you describe your setup?

Comment: Note that this won't work at all if you expect your shared library to be trusted. Non-global shared libraries are untrusted, so beware.

Answer (score 0):

There is the 3rd party [Jenkins Pipeline Unit testing framework](https://github.com/lesfurets/JenkinsPipelineUnit).

While it does not yet cover all features of pipeline, it is well documented and maintained so that I would consider starting using it (once I revisit our Jenkins setup).

Comment: Hey Steve, have you tested it and if so can you confirm this allows you to edit the shared groovy library? I read the doc and have not found my confirmation there

Comment: It's about unit testing. It helps you to develop and verify locally (or in CI). You only "edit" (i.e. push) after tests ran successfully.